# PHP iSDK is not working when deploy on Ubuntu cloud server

Tags: php, ubuntu, xml-rpc, windows-7-x64, infusionsoft

I have written some custom webservices to communicate with Infusionsoft. I want to fetch the Custom Field from Infusionsoft on the basis of EmailId.
I have used following SDK to fulfill my requirements: https://github.com/infusionsoft/PHP-iSDK

The issue is that when I test my code in my local machine it runs fine. My local machine contains Windows 7 and wamp server.

But when I deploy it on my cloud server that is based on Ubuntu. it doesnt work. I have already installed apache server on ubuntu..

I have put some debug points in isdk.php file within some functions.. These are the logs from them on each machine:

Local Machine - Windows 7:

```
In Find By Email Method
***In method caller***
Response From Call: Array
Custom field from Infusionsoft: 20130803T07:46:03
```

Cloud Server - Ubuntu:

```
In Find By Email Method
***In method caller***
Response From Call: 0
```

It seems it gets connected successfully to Infusionsoft but it doesnt return output properly. I have used same request parameters on both.

What I am missing here?? Is it something to do with xmlrpc?? I have placed the xmlrpc directory on ubuntu as well.. but it didnt worked out...

Any quick response would be appreciated.

Thanks

Zunair

Comment: Please add your PHP version on wamp and the ubuntu server. Also post the part of your code you are seeing the issue on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide your version of PHP I can only tell you to check your PHP versions and make sure the ubuntu server is at least 5.3.

Print out your response you get from infusionsoft, it should be in the form of an array object and you might have a different message. Perhaps a throttling issue.  It looks like the response you are printing out is just some variables you are echoing.

The last thing I can think of to check is the location of the ubuntu machine. If I recall correctly infusionsoft has some groups of IPs blocked from accessing the API. I doubt this is your issue but it is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your response.. I got it working..

The first issue was that infusionsofts logs were not working for me... I did fixed them first and they showed me what was the actual reason..

They were using curl for sending the requests.. In my local machine curl was installed and in ubuntu I didnt have it with me... So, I installed it there.. and then it came back to life.. :)